# The 'xmlns' attribute is bound to the reserved namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/'

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, terminal, infragistics

I'm using a terminal application a predecessor wrote, using Infragistics to process some SQL data into excel report templates.

It works fine for some sets of data, but it throws the following: `The 'xmlns' attribute is bound to the reserved namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/'`

Nowhere in the App config is any `xmlns` defined, and I'm at a loss. I can share code, please help me figure out what's relevant.

Comment: Maybe relevant? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23102791/how-to-set-namespace-in-xml-attribute

Comment: The problem here is not in working out what the error means, but where it's coming from. Somewhere in your system there is a piece of software (probably an XML parser) applying this rule to some data, and you need to find where that is, and we can't really help you do that.

Comment: @Shnugo  - I had to step away from this problem to work on other things, but I'll be checking with the rest of my team and trying to get to the bottom of it. I'll resolve this question in the near future.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference/searchability, the Xerces error message for this problem is as follows:

> [Fatal Error] try.xml:2:47: The prefix "xmlns" cannot be bound to any
>   namespace explicitly; neither can the namespace for "xmlns" be bound
>   to any prefix explicitly.

To resolve the problem, search the XML document for `http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/`.  Any of the following settings would be a violation:

```
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/"
xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/"
xmlns:xmlns="anything"
```

possibly with spaces before and/or after the `=` sign, `'` rather than `"`, etc.

The `xmlns` namespace name cannot be reused or redefined.  You'll have to correct the default namespace setting (change `xmlns=` to something else) or remove it.

Comment: This project doesn't have an XML file - any ideas where else I could look?

Comment: Then look for consumption of an XML document that's being used temporarily if not a part of your program's input or output.   The message is coming from an XML parser somewhere in your pipeline or inner operation of your program.

Answer (score 0):

In a comment you state

> This project doesn't have an XML file

But in your question you state

> SQL data into excel report templates

Modern Excel files are XML based...

Just navigate to any related Excel file and open it with a ZIP application. You can change the file extension to `.zip` and just double click this.

I'm, prette sure, that your application is generating such a XML formatted Excel file...